# How do I find single attribute value in the list of objects in scala

Tags: scala

I need to get the single attribute *uuid* and not *Seq(UUID)* from below class

`case class Country(uuid: UUID, name: String, code:String)`

```
val countries = Seq(
                  Country(20354d7a-e4fe-47af-8ff6-187bca92f3f9, "Afghanistan", "AFG"),
                  Country(caa8b54a-eb5e-4134-8ae2-a3946a428ec7,"Albania", "ALB"), 
                  Country(bd2cbad1-6ccf-48e3-bb92-bc9961bc011e, "Algeria", "DZA")
              )
```

val xyz: UUID = Country_uuid_from_countries

I tried `val UUIDs = countries.map(_.uuid)` but it returs Seq[UUID]

```
UUIDs: Seq[UUID] = List(20354d7a-e4fe-47af-8ff6-187bca92f3f9,
                           caa8b54a-eb5e-4134-8ae2-a3946a428ec7,
                           bd2cbad1-6ccf-48e3-bb92-bc9961bc011e
                   )
```

How do I just get UUID?

Comment: I have to just pick the uuid one by one and assign this to another class at the same time. Something like this:

`AnotherCountry(
          countryUuid = Country_uuid_from_countries
        )`

Comment: which UUID you want to get? back and what is the structure of your other class? and if you will assign that UUID to different class you gonna get List[AnotherClass] not the UUID can you please tell us more specifically what you want to do

Comment: I got it the way @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez said: `countries.map(country => AnotherCountry(countryUuid = country.uuid))`. Thank you.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez can you post an answer that can be accepted? That way we don't have too many answered-but-unanswered questions flying around :D

Comment: @fresskoma Yeah, sorry. I just added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a **List** of **Countries**, and a function *(logic)* for transforming one **Country** into **AnotherCountry**. And what you really want at the end is another **List** of **AnotherCountries**.

That is a well know problem. Every time you have a value `A` inside a context `F[_]` *(a **List** is a context of multiplicity)*, and a function `A => B`. And you want to apply this transformation preserving the context to get an `F[B]` as a result.
Then you can use `def map[F[_], A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]`.

In the case of **Scala**, is common that the context themselves provide these functions as **methods**.
So, the only thing you need to do is this:

```
final case class Country(uuid: UUID, name: String, code: String)
final case class AnotherCountry(uuid: UUID)

val countries = List(
  Country(20354d7a-e4fe-47af-8ff6-187bca92f3f9, "Afghanistan", "AFG"),
  Country(caa8b54a-eb5e-4134-8ae2-a3946a428ec7,"Albania", "ALB"), 
  Country(bd2cbad1-6ccf-48e3-bb92-bc9961bc011e, "Algeria", "DZA")
)

val anotherCountires = countries.map { country =>
  AnotherCountry(uuid = country.uuid)
}
```